# Evaluate the following limit probably by Riemann Sum: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin\left(\frac{(2k-1)a}{n^2}\right)$

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

I've tried solving the following limit and I think that it might be possible to transform the sequence into a Riemann Sum.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin\left(\frac{(2k-1)a}{n^2}\right), \\ a \in \mathbb{R}$$

First, I've multiplied and divided by $n$ so I could use ${1\over n}$ as $\Delta x$ and turn it into an integral on $[0, 1]$. Since we have that $(2k - 1)$ in the limit, I thought it would be a good idea to use a midpoint Riemann Sum. So, $x_k^* = \frac{2k - 1}{2n}$
But I just have no idea what to do with the $n^2$ and the $n$ that I've multiplied.

Is this the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using complex numbers:
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sin\left(\frac{(2k-1)a}{n^2}\right)=\Im\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}z^{2k-1}\right)=
\Im\left(\frac{z (z^{2n} - 1)}{z^2 - 1}\right)= ...$$
where $z=e^{i\cdot \frac{a}{n^2}}$
$$...=\Im\left(\frac{\left(\cos{\frac{a}{n^2}} + i\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}\right)\left(\cos{\frac{2a}{n}}-1 + i\sin{\frac{2a}{n}}\right)}{\cos{\frac{2a}{n^2}}-1 + i\sin{\frac{2a}{n^2}}}\right)=\\
\Im\left(\frac{\left(\cos{\frac{a}{n^2}} + i\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}\right)
\left(\cos{\frac{2a}{n}}-1 + i\sin{\frac{2a}{n}}\right)
\color{red}{\left(\cos{\frac{2a}{n^2}}-1 - i\sin{\frac{2a}{n^2}}\right)}}{\left(\cos{\frac{2a}{n^2}}-1\right)^2 + \left(\sin{\frac{2a}{n^2}}\right)^2}\right)=\\
\Im\left(\frac{4\cdot\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}\cdot\sin{\frac{a}{n}}\cdot\left(\cos{\frac{a}{n}} + i \sin{\frac{a}{n}}\right)}{2-2\cdot\cos{\frac{2a}{n^2}}}\right)=\\
\frac{2\cdot\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}\cdot\sin{\frac{a}{n}}\cdot\sin{\frac{a}{n}}}{1-\cos{\frac{2a}{n^2}}}=
\frac{2\cdot\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}\cdot\sin^2{\frac{a}{n}}}{2\cdot\sin^2{\frac{a}{n^2}}}=
\color{blue}{\frac{\sin^2{\frac{a}{n}}}{\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}}}$$

Finally
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2{\frac{a}{n}}}{\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}}=
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2{\frac{a}{n}}}{\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)^2} \cdot \frac{\frac{a}{n^2}}{\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)^2}{\frac{a}{n^2}}=a$$

---

**Some elaborations** on the calculations above

$$\left(\cos{\frac{a}{n^2}} + i\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}\right)
\left(\cos{\frac{2a}{n}}-1 + i\sin{\frac{2a}{n}}\right)
\color{red}{\left(\cos{\frac{2a}{n^2}}-1 - i\sin{\frac{2a}{n^2}}\right)}=\\
e^{i\cdot \frac{a}{n^2}} \left(e^{i\cdot \frac{2a}{n}}-1\right) \color{red}{\left(e^{-i\cdot \frac{2a}{n^2}}-1\right)}=
\left(e^{i\cdot \frac{2a}{n}}-1\right) \color{red}{\left(e^{-i\cdot \frac{a}{n^2}}-e^{i\cdot \frac{a}{n^2}}\right)}=...$$
[which from](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sine.html) $\sin{z}=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ is 
$$...=\left(e^{i\cdot \frac{2a}{n}}-1\right)\cdot\color{red}{(-2i)\cdot\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}}=
e^{i\cdot \frac{a}{n}}
\color{blue}{\left(e^{i\cdot \frac{a}{n}}-e^{-i\cdot \frac{a}{n}}\right)}
\cdot\color{red}{(-2i)\cdot\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}}=\\
\left(\cos{\frac{a}{n}}+i\sin{\frac{a}{n}}\right)\color{blue}{(2i)\cdot\sin{\frac{a}{n}}}\cdot\color{red}{(-2i)\cdot\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}}=\\
4\cdot\left(\cos{\frac{a}{n}}+i\sin{\frac{a}{n}}\right)\cdot\color{blue}{\sin{\frac{a}{n}}}\cdot\color{red}{\sin{\frac{a}{n^2}}}$$
Other results used are

- $1-\cos{x}=2\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}$ and
- $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't studied much complex analysis (I'm in high school, I've just read some things online). Wouldn't $z \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$? Also, is the limit $\lim \Im(f(x)) = \Im(\lim f(x))$?

Comment: You can simplify it further using the fact that $e^{i x}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$.

Comment: Now I see where this is going. Thank you very much. It's not too deep into complex analysis so I can use it.

Comment: Yes, indeed ... I am sorry, I am a bit slow at typing.

Comment: I actually don't quite understand the next step after the red part. It's different that what I thought it would have been. Did you multiply everything out and use trigonometric identities to turn products into sums?

Comment: @StefanOctavian yes ... but you can simply if further by considering imaginary part only after "opening the brackets" and multiplying term by term (leave denominator as is, it's already a real number).

Comment: I obtain $a$ as limit by simple considerations.

Comment: @StefanOctavian does the additional section, explaining the calculations, help?

Comment: @StefanOctavian there was a typo after all ... fixed.

Comment: Isn’t it in the last step $2-2\cos (2a/n^2)$?

Comment: Yep, I missed the $n^2$.

Comment: I was sure there was a mistake somewhere since the limit is clearly $a$. Nice method though.

Comment: God bless you! Thank you really much. I was struggling with those calculations. That part is really explicative and you are a great help. +1

Comment: Try to fix you should obtain the same result.

Comment: That’s fine now! Anyway really I think that an approach by first order approximation is mote straightforward and simple. Maybe we can simplify further the approach using only basic standard limits. I’ll take a look to that later.

Comment: @user it only looks complicated because of the additional explanatory material :)

Comment: I mean complicated  as manipulation indeed there was some mistake and typo. It’s a very giod solution but I think that at least a check by first order expansion is useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

We have that by first order expansion for $\sin x=x+o(x)$

$$ \sin\left(\frac{(2k-1)a}{n^2}\right)=\frac{(2k-1)a}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\right)$$

and since $\sum _{k=1}^{n} k=\frac{n(n+1)}2$ we obtain

$$\sum _{k=1}^{n} \frac{(2k-1)a}{n^2}=\frac{an(n+1)}{n^2}-\frac a n+o(1)=a+o(1)\to a$$

---

**Edit**

From the foundamental limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}x=1$ we have that by definition of little-o notation

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x-x}x=0 \iff \sin x - x = o(x)$$

therefore indicating with $a_k(n)=\frac{(2k-1)a}{n^2} \to 0$ we have $\forall k \le n$

$$\sin (a_k(n)) - a_k(n) = o(a_k(n))$$

therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin (a_k(n))=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[\sin (a_k(n))-a_k(n)\right]+\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}o(a_k(n))+\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(n)$$

and since [$o( f(n) ) + o( g(n) ) = o( f(n) + g(n) )$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1258661/505767) we have that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}o(a_k(n)))=o\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(n)\right)=o(a)$$

we obtain

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin (a_k(n))=a+o(a)\to a$$

Comment: I need a rigurous proof and asymptotic bounds (although I have read a lot about them online and I think I understand them) are not in my curriculum. Also, the other answer which is really rigurous and I've verified it's correct has 0 as a final result

Comment: Sorry I don’t know your background but this way to calculate the limit for the sum is absolutely rigorous. Maybe I have a mistake in the elaboration, I’ll take a look to that but the method is absolutely fine.

Comment: Ok, but it's still not what I need. I'm pretty sure that first row comes from the Taylor Series of sin, which, again, is not in my curriculum and I should have added this in my question, sorry.

Comment: Note that first order expansion for sin function just requires the concept of derivative. Is that in your CV? Anyway I don’t understand the different result at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I will study derivatives. But not this semester. However, I won't study Taylor Series. This proofs seems ok, but I cannot show it to my teacher as we haven't studied this stuff. It's interesting that the result is different than the result in the other answer

Comment: For the past hour I've been trying to grasp your answer for my mathematical development, but I'm at a loss to understand how summing up those $o(\frac{k}{n^2})$ gives something that is $o(1)$. Also, I guessed that $o(kf(x)) = o(f(x))$, is that right? If it's not, how is $o(\frac{(2k-1)a}{n^2}) = o(\frac{k}{n^2})$? I miss a solid asymptotical analysis background

Comment: @StefanOctavian I'm going to add something on that.

Comment: @StefanOctavian I've added a detailed solution for the method by little-o notation.